# BSON Object Being Partially Deserialized

Tags: json, deserialization, bson

I'm trying to deserialize a BSON HTTP Response Message from a Web API call into a custom type.

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1234");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));
            HttpResponseMessage result;

            result = await client.GetAsync("/endpoint/");

            MediaTypeFormatter[] formatters = new MediaTypeFormatter[] {
                new BsonMediaTypeFormatter()
            };

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    RootObject res = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>(formatters);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
```

I know the Web API is returning BSON, I checked through Fiddler and the above code actually does deserialize most things correctly in the RootObject. It appears that all of the derived classes are not being deserialized and are just being input into the object as null. Here is an example of a derived class that is not being deserialized.

RootObject.Events.Teams.Linescores

RootObject

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "RootObject")]
[Serializable] 
public class  RootObject: infoBase
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 30)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Order = 30)]
    public IEnumerable<eventInfo> events { get; set; }

    public RootObject() { }
}
```

Events Object

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "event")]
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(subEventTeam))]
public class eventInfo : infoBase
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 170)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Order = 170)]
    public List<eventTeamBase> teams { get; set; }

    public eventInfo() { }
}
```

Teams Base and Specific Team Type

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "team")]
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(bbLinescoreInfo))]
public class eventTeamBase : infoBase {

     [DataMember(Order = 20)]
     [JsonProperty(Order = 20)]
     public string location { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Order = 30, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
     [JsonProperty(Order = 30, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
     public string nickname { get; set; }

     [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "linescores", Order = 130)]
     [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Order = 130)]
     public IEnumerable<linescoreBase> linescores { get; set; }

  public eventTeamBase() { }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "team")]
[Serializable]
public class  subEventTeam : eventTeamBase
{
   public subEventTeam () { }
}
```

Linescore Base and Specific Object

```
[DataContract(Name = "linescores", Namespace = "")]
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(subLinescoreInfo))]
public class linescoreBase : infoBase
{
    public bool isProcessing = false;
    public int teamId { get; set; }

    public linescoreBase() { }
}
[DataContract(Name = "linescores", Namespace = "")]
[Serializable] public class  subLinescoreInfo : linescoreBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public int inning { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int? score { get; set; }

    public subLinescoreInfo() { };
}
```

Here is the deserialized (and then re-serialized) part of the response that isn't working output into JSON.

```
{
"status":"OK",
"recordCount":1,
"RootObject":[
{
  "events":[
  {
      "teams":[
      {
         "location":"Tallahassee",
         "nickname":"Razors",
         "linescores":[
            {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
       }
   }
 }
```

}

So as you can see, it is filling in some information correctly (There is a lot more, I've cut down significantly just to illustrate the problem). But the linescores are returning null. As mentioned, the data is returning correctly and it is not null.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong with the known types and I've tried numerous combinations of putting them in different places and the results don't change. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and trying wrong things, I found a similar solution in another thread.
[JSON Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725751/web-api-converting-json-to-complex-object-type-dto-with-inheritance)

I solved this by doing pretty much that exact same thing but with BSON instead of JSON.

This is the code that I needed to add in the global config file of the Web API

```
BsonMediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
bsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
bsonFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("accept", "bson", "application/bson");
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(bsonFormatter);
```

And this code went into the client.

```
BsonMediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
bsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
MediaTypeFormatter[] formatters = new MediaTypeFormatter[] {
   bsonFormatter
};
```

Everything else remained the same and was deserialized without incident.